# Using $_SESSON in a foreach loop to pass a record id without using GET

Tags: php, session, foreach

I am trying to pass a SESSION variable so that the user can edit something but when I use $_SESSION, the last record ID is the one set.

I read that I should use

```
$_SESSION['property_id'] = array();
  foreach($property_data->results() as $pdata) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>' . $pdata->prop_name . '</li>';  
    $prop_num = $pdata->id;
    $calendar_record = DB::getInstance()->singleCalendar('reservations', array('user_id', '=', $user_id, 'property_id', '=', $prop_num));
    $_SESSION['property_id'][] = $prop_num;
    if($calendar_record->count()) {
        echo '<li><a href="calendar-details.php">EDIT BOOKINGS</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="calendar-add.php">CREATE FIRST BOOKING</a>';         
    }

    echo '</ul>';               
};
```

which I did and I have a _SESSION variable available on the next page as an array but what I don't understand is how do I know which one I am after, which one they actually clicked on?

So what I want to do is pass a SESSION variable but set it to the correct value when looping through numerous records and have that variable available on the next page.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't know exactly what you want to do. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Why can't you use GET? It would make your life easier if you could just use something like this: '?id=$yourid'

Comment: I want to hide the variable being passed. I don't want the person to be able to see my GET variables at all. $_SESSION is perfect except that in the loop, if you don't create an array, you get the last record overwriting the SESSION. I want the visitor to be able to go to calendar-details.php without having to have calendar-details.php?property_id=6

Comment: because if the GET variable is visible, they can change it. There are lots of things that I am keeping them from doing, I don't need to also keep them from being able to change GET variables when I could use a SESSION variable which I am already doing for their user_id

Comment: you could crypt the id and send it via get. you need some identifier, becouse if php /html is written you have no chance to know what the user wants to click until he clicks it.